# Calculating the correct z score

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The question is: Assume that GRE Verbal scores approximate a normal curve with a mean of 500 and a standard deviation of 100. A university admissions office has decided to admit only those applicants who score in the top 10 percent of the GRE Verbal distribution. In order to be admitted, a student must have received a score of ____ or higher?

I know that this is a problem of converting proportions to z scores and then using the z scores to calculate the GRE score. I did that but got a different z score from the textbook. I got a z score of 2.56 but the textbook inputted a z score of 1.28 i.e half of what I got.

My reasoning is that the top 10 percent of applicants would lie to the right of the area under the graph i.e 0.1 and so I used python to calculate the area under the graph for a proportion of 0.9 to the left (python calculates the left tail).

what am I doing wrong that my z score is twice that of the textbook's?  Help please.

Comment: how did you come up with $2.56$ ? A z-table clearly shows that $0.90 = 1.28$

Comment: My bad. I forgot to remove a 2 that I used to multiply an earlier calculation. A mistake. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Top $10\%$ is clearly

$$z\geq\Phi^{-1}(0.9)\approx 1.28$$

Then passing to your rv you get

$$x=1.28\times 100+500=628$$

**Z-table**

[image]